# ¿Como puedo cambiar la acción de un botón de un JFrame a público?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, matisse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso Netbeans y quisiera saber como convertir ActionEvent de un botón: `btnFIlesActionPerformed`, de *private void* a *public void* si este fue creado usando el editor visual.

Comment: Estás usando el editor visual?

Comment: sí lo estoy usando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el tab de propiedades realmente hay tres partes:

1. Propiedades
2. Eventos
3. Generación de código

Así que ve al tab `Code`, selecciona `Variable Modifiers` y te aparecerá un cuadro de diálogo con un combo desplegable para cambiar los modificadores de acceso

[image: tab de propiedades]

Ahora si lo que quieres es modificar la generación de eventos déjame decirte que lo normal es no hacerlo ya que romperías con la encapsulación que es uno de los 4 pilares de la POO.

Si aún así deseas ir en contra de los cánones, puedes usar esta pequeña treta, que si bien no es modificar la generación de código si te permite logarra lo que quieres:

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { // no editable                                       
    String nombres = txtnombre.getText();
    // mi demás código autogenerado
}// no editable   

public void abtnSaveActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { // editable                                       
    btnSaveActionPerformed(evt);
}// editable
```

Adicionalmente [ya levanté el issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-5063) con la gente de apache.

Comment: ya lo intenté y sigue en private, eso solo cambia el "java.swing.JButton" a public :c

Comment: y eso es lo que querías no, cambiarlo de private a public?

Comment: pero quiero cambiar el "private void btnFilesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)" a public, no el "public javax.swing.JButton btnFiles;"

Comment: Entendido, por favor edita tu pregunta en lo que lo intento...

Comment: ya lo entendí, pero como hago para que ejecute el segundo evento?

Comment: si te fijas el nombre es diferente, así que lo referencias por el segundo nombre

Answer (score 0):

Sólo en el código en lugar de `private`cambialo por  `public`

```
public void btnFilesActionPerformed
```

Esto lo hará público

Comment: estoy usando JFrame :/

Comment: Edita tu pregunta

Comment: ya que el codigo que proporcionas es por un  btnFilesActionPerformed

Comment: no hay necesidad de editar nada, lee el título

Comment: Si ya lo lei, pero en tus imagenes viene otra cosa.

Comment: cuanta incoherencia

Comment: Porque? si dice como cambiar la accion de un boton de private a public

Comment: @ivanRAMIREZ yo ya había editado la pregunta para agregar la etiqueta de matisse, ya que como verás en los comentarios de la pregunta esta usando el diseñador visual de netbeans que se llama... Matisse. Saludos cordiales.